# sending props via the react-router Link component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with sending props through the Link component of the react-router.
This is my component that is responsible for displaying a specific element:

```
const ItemRecipe = ({ recipe }) => {
  const { label, image } = recipe.recipe;
  return (
    <li>
      <p> {label} </p>
      <img src={image} alt="food" />


      <Link to={{pathname: `/meals/${label}`, params: recipe }}>

        <p>next</p>
      </Link >
    </li>
  );
}
```

After clicking on I want to open the page with a specific recipe. This component looks like this

```
class DetailsRecipe extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipe: props.match.params.recipe
    }
    console.log(this.state.recipe);
  }
  render () {
     <div>
         lorem lorem

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`console.log(this.state.recipe)` displays `undefined`.
how to fix this error? How to correctly send data through the Link component of the react-router?

I looked at similar topics on a stackoverflow but it did not help to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another look at the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) of the Link component. The properties allowed inside the `to` object are:

- pathname: A string representing the path to link to.
- search: A string representation of query parameters.
- hash: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.
- state: State to persist to the location.

I guess you want to use `state` instead of `params`.

**EDIT:**

So your code would look like this:

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/meals/${label}`, state: {"recipe": recipe} }}>
```

Then you can access the `state` inside the linked component like this:

```
this.state = {
  recipe: props.location.state.recipe
};
```

Comment: I changed props.match.params.recipe to props.match.params and it`s ok  but 
I passes only the name, not the whole recipe object

Comment: I don't really understand what you've changed. And did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I changed  this.state = {
      recipe: props.match.params
    }  and it is ok. But this not my goal, I want pass object through Link in react router

Comment: See my updated answer for an example of the state usage.

Comment: I get - TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipe' of undefined

Comment: Are you using anything like [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options) to inject props to routed components? That might explain why `props.match` is okay but `props.location` is not.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you. My problem has been solved. :)